# use more than one property in css method in jquery

Tags: jquery

how I can use more than one property in css method in jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#dv1").click(function(){
            $(this).css("height","200px")
            $(this).css("backgroundColor","red")
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify all the CSS properties in object form:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#dv1").click(function(){
        $(this).css({
            height: "200px",
            backgroundColor: "red"
        });
    });
});
```